Issue with Transcribing Video Files Using OpenAI's Whisper Model in a Next.js API Route
I'm currently working on a Next.js project where I'm trying to implement video file transcription using OpenAI's Whisper model. I've set up an API route to handle the transcription, but I'm encountering an issue where the transcription process completes successfully (I can log the transcription text), but my API route still returns an error indicating that no text was returned.
Here's the relevant part of my API route code:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import OpenAI from 'openai'; 

export async function POST(request: Request) { 
try { const formData = await request.formData(); const videoFile = formData.get('videoFile');

if (!videoFile || !(videoFile instanceof Blob)) { 
    throw new Error('No video file provided or the file is not a Blob'); 
}

const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY, });

const transcriptionResponse = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create(
{ 
file: videoFile, 
model: 'whisper-1', 
language: 'en', 
response_format: 'text'
});

console.log('Full transcription response:', 
JSON.stringify(transcriptionResponse, null, 2));

if (!transcriptionResponse || !transcriptionResponse.text) {
    console.error( 'Transcription response or text missing:', 
transcriptionResponse ); 
    throw new Error('Transcription failed or no text returned');
}

console.log(`Transcription result: ${transcriptionResponse.text}`);

return NextResponse.json(
{ transcription: transcriptionResponse.text }); } 
catch (error) { console.error('Error transcribing video:', error); 
const message = error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error'; return NextResponse.json( { error: 'Failed to transcribe video', details: message }, { status: 500 } ); } }

Here is also the frontend side of things:
function TranscriptionForm() {
  const [videoFile, setVideoFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [transcription, setTranscription] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
      setVideoFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!videoFile) {
      setError('Please select a video file to transcribe.');
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);
    setError('');
    setTranscription('');

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('videoFile', videoFile);

      const response = await fetch('/api/transcribe', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setTranscription(data.transcription);
        console.log('Transcription result:', data.transcription);
      } else {
        setError(data.error || 'Failed to transcribe video');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      setError('Failed to transcribe video');
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type='file'
        max={25 * 1024 * 1024}
        accept='audio/*,video/*'
        name='file'
        onChange={handleFileChange}
      />
      <button type='submit' disabled={isLoading}>
        {isLoading ? 'Transcribing...' : 'Transcribe'}
      </button>
      {transcription && <p>Transcription: {transcription}</p>}
      {error && <p className='error'>{error}</p>}
    </form>
  );
}


Do you see the "Transcription response or text missing:" in your console?
